# How can I manage a pipe going up and a pipe going down a binary tree of processes?

Tags: c, fork, pipe, file-descriptor

I am trying to create a binary tree of processes in which each parent is connected to its two children through pipes.

Problem:  Parent process A creates two processes(B and C) and two pipes, one for each process.  Their file descriptors are stored into fd.  In the second iteration, B spawns its two children.  B overwrites the file descriptors stored into fd with the new pipe's file descriptors.  After spawning my n number of levels, the only pipes that remain are the leaf nodes to their parents(up one level).

I've tested this theory and the only things being communicated are between at the bottom of the tree, leaf to up-one-level.  I have to make it so the leaf nodes can communicate all the way up the tree to the master process.

I am new to pipes so I could be off about my explanation.

Is my understanding correct, and also what should I do to fix this issue?

Sample Code:

```
#define READ 0
#define WRITE 1

int fd[2][2];

void
spawnChildren(int levels)
{
    if(levels == 0)
       return;

    pipe(fd[0]);
    //spawns 2 children at a single parent
    int pid = fork();
    //parent
    if(pid > 0)
    {
        close(fd[0][WRITE]);
        pipe(fd[1]);
        int pid2 = fork();
        //child B
        if(pid2 == 0)
        {
            close(fd[1][READ]);
            spawnChildren(levels-1);
            return;
        }
        //parent
        else
            close(fd[1][WRITE]);
    }
    //child A
    else
    {
        close(fd[0][READ]);
        spawnChildren(levels-1);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hopefully you don't need too many processes.  Making a small tree is probably OK, but trying to build a tree with thousands of individual processes is probably not going to scale.

Comment: It seems you're not tracking the pipe back to a processes parent anywhere? Each process except the root and the leaves needs to keep track of three pipes - one to each child and one to its parent.

Comment: To keep track of the pipe going up, should I use dup2?  ex: The parent's left read would be equivalent to the left child's up write pipe.  Is that correct?

Comment: Have you thought about reading and writing to files instead of pipes? This could simplify things depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have to use pipes as this is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the root process has opened *two* fd's to communicate with its two children. Then they just open other, independent pipes.

How can the root process communicate with its nephews when they're *four*?

You need to keep *all* fd's open; each process must get input from its children, and pass it to its parent; you need some sort of protocol to sort them out. The same for data going down.

For example, the root parent wants to communicate with its left child's right child's left child:

- it sends RL.HELLO WORLD to its left child
- the left child sees the R and sends #L.HELLO WORLD to its right child
- the right child receives #L.HELLO WORLD and sends ##.HELLO WORLD to its left child
- the left child receives ##.HELLO WORLD and knows the message's for it
- the left child answers sending ##.I HEAR YOU to its parent
- the parent sees its left child talking, converts the last # to L and sends up
- the parent sees its right child saying #L.I HEAR YOU and sends RL.I HEAR YOU up
- the root receives RL.I HEAR YOU from its left child and knows who originated it

Of course at that point each process must also have a queue for incoming and outgoing messages.

Even communicating only between root and leaves would require queues and message passing; it would only allow to do without the "R#L" protocol, but given its simplicity, that's a very small saving.

Comment: Message passing only goes up, meaning children are the only ones able to write to their parent.  Parents are the only ones able to read from their respective children.  Message passing down is not required.  The application of this program is in a parallel external merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is one thread or process listening (reading) each pipe and then writing that up to the corresponding pipe. Essentially each 'node' needs two threads or processes doing this, one for each child.

This isn't very scalable, and depending on what you're trying to do you may want to re-evaluate if you can't design it a little better. One suggestion would be to have your leaf nodes writing to temporary files instead of pipes and then having your top level read those files intelligently instead of trying to manage all of these pipes through forks. Doing this you could cut the number of 'nodes' by a large amount. Just an idea.